# how to test if array contains any value?

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethers.js, hardhat

this is my smart contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint256 public favoriteNumber;

    struct People {
        uint256 favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    People[] public people;

    mapping(string => uint256) public nameToFavoriteNumber;

    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256) {
        return 
        favoriteNumber;
    }
    function addPerson(string memory _name, uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        people.push(People(_favoriteNumber, _name));
        nameToFavoriteNumber[_name] = _favoriteNumber;
    }
}
```

if I tried to access people array's 0th index through hardhat like this

```js
  let peopleArray = await simpleStorage.people("0");
  console.log(`People ${peopleArray}`);
```

I am getting

```shell
Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="people(uint256)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.6.4)
    at Logger.makeError (E:\Learning_Programming\Solidity\SimeplStorageHardHat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:261:28)
    at Logger.throwError (E:\Learning_Programming\Solidity\SimeplStorageHardHat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:273:20)
    at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (E:\Learning_Programming\Solidity\SimeplStorageHardHat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\interface.ts:427:23)
    at Contract.<anonymous> (E:\Learning_Programming\Solidity\SimeplStorageHardHat\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:400:44)
    at step (E:\Learning_Programming\Solidity\SimeplStorageHardHat\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
    at Object.next (E:\Learning_Programming\Solidity\SimeplStorageHardHat\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
    at fulfilled (E:\Learning_Programming\Solidity\SimeplStorageHardHat\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:20:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  reason: null,
  code: 'CALL_EXCEPTION',
  method: 'people(uint256)',
  data: '0x',
  errorArgs: null,
  errorName: null,
  errorSignature: null,
  address: '0x5FC8d32690cc91D4c39d9d3abcBD16989F875707',
  args: [ '0' ],
  transaction: {
    data: '0x9e7a13ad0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    to: '0x5FC8d32690cc91D4c39d9d3abcBD16989F875707',
    from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266'
  }
}
```

but if I access the people array after adding some value

```js
let transactionResponse = await simpleStorage.addPerson("john", "13531");
await transactionResponse.wait(1);

let peopleArray = await simpleStorage.people("0");
console.log(`People ${peopleArray}`);
```

I am getting the value(because it has some value right?)
my question is how do I check whether an array is empty or not? through hardhat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i need to create a function that exposes this information separately, e.g.:

```
function numOfPeople() public view returns (uint256) {
  return people.length;
}
```

When calling this function, if it returns anything above 0, it would not be empty.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply check that by an if-else statement with the array.length method:

```
if (peopleArray.length === 0) {
 return console.log("Array is empty") 
} else { 
return console.log("Array Not Empty") 
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Your `people`  array is public, you can call `await simpleStorage.people.length;`  directly in test instead of creating the function `numOfPeople()` in the contract as mentioned in the previous answer

Comment: It doesn't work people is a getter function that expect a index parameter.

Comment: What do you mean it doesnt work ? I tested it before putting the comment.